# Rewarded Ads - Disallowed Rewarded Implementation

Tags: android, admob, rewardedvideoad

Rewarded ads may only be served after a user affirmatively opts to view a rewarded ad. Additionally, a user must opt to view each rewarded ad individually and cannot opt-in to automatically seeing rewarded ads.

Not understand what admob want to say my application ads blocked.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you trigger to open rewarded video advertisement with some action and your users cannot know/infer that they will watch a rewarded video and they will earn something when they watch the video as intended.

Here is the explanation from official documentation

> Before displaying a rewarded ad to users, you must present the user with an explicit choice to view rewarded ad content in exchange for a reward. Rewarded ads must always be an opt-in experience.

Here is the example from the same document, the button should be self-explanatory
[image]

I recommend to read [this page](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/rewarded-ads) for the details

Answer (score 0):

Rewarded ads may only be served after a user affirmatively opts to view a rewarded ad. Additionally, a user must opt to view each rewarded ad individually and

> cannot opt-in to automatically seeing rewarded ads.

Answer (score 0):

Rewarded ads are shown once users give explicit permission to view that ad. You might've triggered it in such a way that it is getting shown without user permission. I think you need to work on the trigger.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).